# Modern page: Show FILTER PANE in Library webpart. Possible?

Tags: web-part, document-library, filter, modern

I am using this modern "**filter pane**" in my library, but when  I use a Document Library Webpart to show this library as part of  a page, the filter pane is not present. How can I show  the Filter Pane while using a library webpart?

The filter pane is a big plus for the end user to filter the library based on metadata. It is a bummer if this is only available in a Library it selves and not in Library webparts